# GNU make: ifneq always evaluating to true

Tags: makefile

I'm fighting with makefiles, again... and I need some help.

```
check-fleet:
    LOCAL_VERSION = $(shell fleetctl -version)
    REMOTE_VERSION = $(shell ssh core@$(FLEETCTL_TUNNEL) fleetctl -version)
    ifneq $(strip $(LOCAL_VERSION)) $(strip $(REMOTE_VERSION))
        $(error Your fleetctl client version should match the server. Local version: $(LOCAL_VERSION), server version: $(REMOTE_VERSION). Uninstall your local version and install the latest build from https://github.com/coreos/fleet/releases)
    endif
```

When this executes, I see that it's indeed shelling out and connecting to the server, but the error ALWAYS occurs, even when I set the value of these variables manually! Additionally, they are always blank in the error statement.

Even if there was an issue with them being set (i.e. if they are blank), then at least they'd be equal and the `ifneq` would never fire.

I'm wondering if this is an issue relating to the two-pass processing of Makefiles, but I tried setting the variables myself manually to known strings that are equal, and the error still fires. I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's critical to understand that the lines of the makefile which are NOT part of a recipe (generally, *not* indented with a TAB) are parsed by make, and the lines of the makefile which ARE part of the recipe (generally, indented with a TAB) are *not* parsed by make; they're passed to the shell and the shell runs them.

So, it's not legal or valid to put make variable assignments or make commands like `ifneq` in a recipe (indented with a TAB).

If you want commands to be run as part of the `check-fleet` target, you have to write a *shell script* in the recipe, not use make constructs.

```
check-fleet:
        LOCAL_VERSION=`fleetctl -version`; \
        REMOTE_VERSION=`ssh core@$(FLEETCTL_TUNNEL) fleetctl -version`; \
        if [ $$LOCAL_VERSION != $$REMOTE_VERSION ]; then \
            echo "Your fleetctl client version should match the server. Local version: $$LOCAL_VERSION, server version: $$REMOTE_VERSION. Uninstall your local version and install the latest build from https://github.com/coreos/fleet/releases"; exit 1; \
        fi
```

Comment: That is hugely helpful, and makes sense - thank you! I have noticed, though, that I can use Make functions within recipes - I use the `$(call ...)` function frequently to call a user-defined function which echoes output in yellow. Is this something I shouldn't be doing?

Comment: Sure, you can use them in recipes: in fact that's often very useful.  All variables and functions are evaluated by make before the recipe is invoked, then the results are sent to the shell.  So, as long as the things you need done can all happen BEFORE the recipe starts, and not rely on any results of commands that the recipe runs (since it won't be run until later) then you can use make functions for that.  My rule of thumb is that you shouldn't use `$(shell ...)` in a recipe (because the recipe itself is a shell script).  And you can't use `ifeq` or other preprocessor commands of course.